# Parse xml using c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an xml like

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:docs='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:etag='W/&quot;C0EARXY8eit7ImA9WhVREE0.&quot;'>

<id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full</id>
<updated>2012-03-17T16:27:24.872Z</updated>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#item' label='item'/>

<title>Available Documents - </title>

<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://docs.google.com'/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-create-media' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full'/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#alt-post' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/file/default/private/full'/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full'/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full'/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/batch'/>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/document'/>

<some more tags />

<entry gd:etag='&quot;E0UXTh9YDSt7ImBr&quot;'>
<some more tags />
<title>hi</title>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#parent' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='alternate' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#icon' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-edit-media' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#alt-edit-media' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007/thumbnail' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
<link rel='edit-media' type='application/atom+xml' href=''/>
...
<some more tags />
...
</entry>
<entry>
...
</entry>
...
```

I want to fetch the attribute `href` of the element `<link>` whose `rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-create-media"`

What I'm doing right now is I'm getting list of nodes with `xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("link");` then I'm iterating through all of them and fetching the first one whose `rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-create-media"`

So essentially I'm looping through all the nodes `<link>` when I'm just interested in those which are next child of node `<feed>` and are not inside node `<entry>`.
A `<feed>` have multiple `<entry>` nodes which in turn have multiple `<link>` tags.
And instead I would like to just get the list of `<link>` which are directly in `<feed>` and not in `<entry>`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use the System.Xml.Linq.XElement classes for working with xml in C#.  If I understand your problem, it could look like this:

```
XElement input = XElement.Load(filename);
foreach(XElement feedChild in input.Elements("feed"))
  foreach(XElement linkChild in feedChild.Elements("link"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use XPath:

```
var nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//link[@rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-create-media']", namespaceManaager)
```

(where `namespaceManaager` is an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) configured to map tag `a` to namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`).

Answer (score 1):

LINQ To XML seems like a good choice for this, since you can easily parse your XML tree.

Have a look at official example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx